# Nova boot error Devstack

Tags: openstack-nova

I uploaded an image to glance, an Ubuntu server 12.04 in a vhd format and when i'm trying to boot that image with nova boot i receive this:

```
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Property                            | Value                                |
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| OS-DCF:diskConfig                   | MANUAL                               |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host                | None                                 |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname | None                                 |
| OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name       | instance-00000004                    |
| OS-EXT-STS:power_state              | 0                                    |
| OS-EXT-STS:task_state               | scheduling                           |
| OS-EXT-STS:vm_state                 | building                             |
| accessIPv4                          |                                      |
| accessIPv6                          |                                      |
| adminPass                           | PK2mwUZ7SJEH                         |
| config_drive                        |                                      |
| created                             | 2012-12-19T17:21:48Z                 |
| flavor                              | m1.tiny                              |
| hostId                              |                                      |
| id                                  | 716c9276-648c-4f90-9e67-43b8f41feb91 |
| image                               | Ubuntu                               |
| key_name                            | key1                                 |
| metadata                            | {}                                   |
| name                                | vm1                                  |
| progress                            | 0                                    |
| security_groups                     | [{u'name': u'default'}]              |
| status                              | BUILD                                |
| tenant_id                           | 73e54a9f1ddc46fa9bd0a99d5e2a1cda     |
| updated                             | 2012-12-19T17:21:54Z                 |
| user_id                             | dc9c0376d5604467b3898082fd270b1c     |
+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/vmware-tools-distrib$ cd /
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ cd /home/ubuntu/devstack/
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/devstack$ nova list
+--------------------------------------+------+--------+----------+
| ID                                   | Name | Status | Networks |
+--------------------------------------+------+--------+----------+
| 716c9276-648c-4f90-9e67-43b8f41feb91 | vm1  | ERROR  |          |
| 77aa0d77-2dae-4d18-a827-f08d0fb2f71a | vm1  | ERROR  |          |
+--------------------------------------+------+--------+----------+
```

So, what may be the problem??
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can access the database to get the detail reason if there is no obvious information in log file, query nova.instance_faults table will give you more information about why this instance became error status.

Answer (score 0):

look at the nova-network.log if there is an error which is related dhcpbridge file, add that line to nova.conf

dhcpbridge = /usr/bin/nova-dhcpbridge

hint: if there is a builted image(nova list) delete it and then restart all nova-* services